# iOS App based on PhoneGap rejected by Apple for "using non-public API"

Tags: iphone, cordova, app-store, appstore-approval, iphone-privateapi

We just built an iOS app based on PhoneGap 0.9.5.1 and got it rejected by Apple with this response:

> Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected
>
> We found the following non-public APIs in your app:
>
> _gsEvent
> setNavigationBar:

The app has multiple UIWebView(s) and a navigation bar to traverse between them. We just wrote HTML/CSS/Javascript for each UIWebView and implemented the basic navigation bar. All the rest is handled by PhoneGap.

Can somebody help with this? Thx!

Comment: You would probably need to forward that email to PhoneGap.

Comment: We have checked our codes and found what we've missing. The PhoneGap has done nothing wrong. Thx for all of your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your version of the PhoneGap Objective C wrapper code to see if it contains any method names that Apple may have reserved for itself.

PhoneGap URL callback functions that significantly extend Javascript's functionality may also be a problem if the app can download any Javascript code from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be best posting this on the PhoneGap site itself.

One basic debug technique you could use is just to open the phonegap source code in xcode. If it gives you any warnings check them for something like "method not found" which means they are calling a function apple hasn't made public (and so officially, and to xcode, doesn't exist).